# Recursion of deep remove does not move past the a match

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

So for deep remove you can be given a linked list and a value. If you find a value in that list you remove and continue on till all values are removed that match the parameter value. Though my program stops once it finds a match.

Examples of what should happen

```
removedeep(3, [1, 2, 3, 4])   --> [1, 2, 4]
         removedeep(3, [1, [2, 3], 4]) --> [1, [2], 4]
         removedeep(3, [1, 2, 4]) --> [1, 2, 4]
         removedeep(3,  --> [1, [2], 4]


def removedeep(x, L):
    '''test if x occurs within the nested list L.

       E.g., removedeep(3, [1, 2, 3, 4])   --> [1, 2, 4]
             removedeep(3, [1, [2, 3], 4]) --> [1, [2], 4]
             removedeep(3, [1, 2, 4]) --> [1, 2, 4]
             removedeep(3,  --> [1, [2], 4]'''

    if not L:
        return []
    elif type(L[0]) == type(x):
        if(L[0] == x):
            return removedeep(x, L[1:])
        else:
            return [L[0]] + removedeep(x, L[1:])
    else:
        return removedeep(x, L[0])

    print(removedeep(4,[1,2,[4],3,5,6]))
```

Though my output is `[1,2]` not `[1,2,3,5,6]`

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing as you seem to have two different names for your function, `removedeep` and `deepMember`. I'm also curious what the expected output would be of `deepMember(3, [[1], 2, 3, 4])`, `deepMember(3, [1, 2, [3] ,4])` and maybe `deepMember(3, [3])`. Can you ever call the function to remove a sublist (e.g. `deepMember([2, 3], [1, [2, 3], 4])`)?

Comment: @Blckknght sorry fixed

Answer (score 0):

Look at this branch:

```
#...
else:
    return removedeep(x, L[0])
```

How about `L[1:]`?
Consider your example, when you enter into this branch, your `L` now is `[[4],3,5,6]`, but you just return `removedeep(4,[4])`.

** Edit version:

```
    else:
        # if you always remove a single element from a list 
        return [removedeep(x, L[0])] + removedeep(x, L[1:])
```

Comment: but what if its [1,2,[4,2],3,5,6] then it removes that whole middle section.

Comment: See my edition. If you  always remove a single element from a list, than you can and should safely wrap that `removedeep(x, L[0])` since it is a sub-list.

Answer (score 0):

When encounter a nested array you call:

```
else:
    return removedeep(x, L[0])
```

This ignores any values after it so given input like `4,[1,2,[4],3,5,6])`, you hit `[4]` and call `removedeep(x, [4])`, but you then have no way of getting to the `3, 5, 6` portion of the array. Somehow you need to include those. The quick dirty way is to add:

```
else:
    return removedeep(x, L[0]) + removedeep(x, L[1:])
```

With that this gives:

```
> print(removedeep(4,[1,2,[4, [90, 4],9],3,[4,5,6]]))
[1, 2, 90, 9, 3, 5, 6]
```